# PHP - Call wordpress functions from an external file in another domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, function

I am making a plugin that receives a key word entered in a form, then process this word and make a search in a web page, when receiving the results (through AJAX), the videos will be screened.

In my script.php instead of echoing all html lines, I used "include" to include a php file (hosted in an external domain) with the html lines and then these are printed in the domain The person using the plugin. Everything works fine but at the moment of wanting to show the lists of categories calling internal functions of Wordpress, the plugin fails, obviously it is because the script is trying to look for these functions from the domain where the file is hosted and not from the local wordpress. How could I do this?

My scrypt.js hosted in the local domain, that is, included in the files of the plugin that the user will download. As you can see it makes a call to a api.php hosted in an external domain.

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var pluginUrl = '<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>' ;
            $('[id^="form-busqueda"]').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'http://example.com/server/api.php',
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#results').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'../../assets/img/loading.gif" />');
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ok, this query will pass through AJAX to my api.php file hosted in another domain and this file will respond with an "include (" results.php ")", the results.php file is also housed in the same external domain where Is my api.php file

api.php

```
<?php
 //A series of validations are made, variables are generated (example $variable1,  and finally the file "results.php" is called that calls all the variables so that finally the content is printed in the site of the client that is using the plugin.
include("results.php");
?>
```

results.php

```
<div class="container">
   <p><?php echo $variable1 ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $variable2 ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $variable3 ?></p>
   <?php 
     $category=addslashes($_GET['cat']);
     $args = array(
'orderby'            => 'name', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'         => 0, 
'selected'           => $category,
'name'               => 'cat_',
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>
</div>
```

The problem is when I invoke Wordpress functions from this file. But I do not know what else I could use. I hope I have been clear enough with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In most web servers (php.ini) there is set to allow files inclusion, so you can not use the include to include the files from a remote address for security reasons.

Or you can use this, where the directive **allow_url_include** must be set to On in php.ini

If you want to read the HTML contents of a remote file though, so for you, it may help to use the **file_get_contents** function instead BUT this will be returned as pure HTML markup code, there won't be any server-side code.